# set 1024*780 Image for all the iDevices

Tags: ios, background-image

I Just started developing an Universal iOS app for which I need to set the Background image.

Instead of using 3~4 different size images for iPhone, iPhone-retina, iPhone5 , iPhone5-retina & iPad, iPad-retina , I Just want to take one Highest resolution Image (say 1024*780), Which I want to use to fit all the above mentioned devices. How???

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sfond-appz.png"]];
```

& it is not occupying the exact screen size for smaller devices. it is shrinking.

Please Advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

If Apple suggests to use different images for each kind of display there is a specific reason, and that reason is memory.
 As display size increases it increases also the memory available on the device that's because bigger images require more memory. Even if you want to resize (not stretching) them at runtime, the first time you open it will occupy that memory until you release it. The memory occupied it doesn't have to deal with the file size.
If you still want to try take a look at this library that will help you to resize (not stretch) images at runtime [NYXImagesKit](https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit)

Comment: Thanks Andrea Garu for reply. I just gone through your above mentioned link! . OMG, iOS really has a lot of stuff to learn & it is not that simple.  In my Android app , I just throwed one background image & it almost fit on any sized mobile... Looking for the same in iOS.

Comment: Don't think about fit, think about memory also in Android, have you checked your app if it works also on low-end devices? sometimes they crash because the haven't enough memory to run.

Comment: true... But iDevices will not face Low Memory issue(I Think!)

Comment: NO , I am not joking... Is it( iDevices will not face Low Memory issue(I Think!)) wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry but is totally wrong, all kind of hardware could have that type of issue, in iOS there is also a specific notication UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification and other methods to handle them

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing in one of my apps in the App Store. On the main menu view, I use a UIImaveView as the background and set the mode to Aspect Fit in Interface Builder. I use struts and springs to keep it aligned to the edges.

For a universal app, you'll create this UIImageView on both the iPhone and iPad story board (or .xib files) and use the same image file.

However, I still have a 2x version for retina displays. So, I use just two images to cover all devices, orientations, and resolutions.

It will consume less memory if you create a background image to fit each device, but you will obviously increase the bundle size. In my case, the goal was to keep the bundle size small (under 50 MB for cellular delivery), and I had memory to spare.

Comment: Thanks ...But I just don't wanna use story boards as I prefer it Programatically., but why to spare will try & let you know

Comment: @user2109817, programatically, it's the same, just do it in code instead of via Interface Builder.